# CSS - Flip image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, drag-and-drop

I am trying to flip images wich are dragged by using jquery 
when I drag the image to the new div, it makes a class. I use `ui.helper.addClass("gemaakt");` and it's working fine!
The thing is, my CSS script is flipping images etc.. but not classes for some reason? Since I drag those images, it puts them into a class

quite difficult to explain, so I decided to post it on JSfiddle so you can get  see it,

http://jsfiddle.net/qbvzwsg2/
http://jsfiddle.net/qbvzwsg2/2/   <- updated version

As you can see, the flip ( at bottom, works correctly ) 
When click on image, it flips flawless, no problem.

But now, drag a card into the box, and click on that image.. 
Nothing happens :(

```
<div class="flip-container">
    <div class="flipper" onclick="this.classList.toggle('flipped')">
        <div class="front">
            <div class="ui-draggable gemaakt dropped"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <img src="./img/test.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

for some reason it can not flip a class

Help someone? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Persijn is correct. The image don't flip. What flips is the entire container, as in the card at the bottom:

```
<div class="flip-container">
    <div class="flipper" onclick="this.classList.toggle('flipped')">
        <div class="front">
            <div class="ui-draggable gemaakt dropped"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <img src="./img/test.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, to make things happen, you could change the HTML of `.cards img` to accomplish that structure and change the draggable to `.cards .flip-container`.

To make it more easy to show you the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qbvzwsg2/6/), I just added this script to prepare the correct structure, instead of changing the HTML:

```
$(".cards img").each(function() {
    $(this).wrap('<div class="front"></div>').parent().wrap('<div class="flipper"></div>').parent().wrap('<div class="flip-container"></div>').append('<div class="back">FLIPPED</div>');
});
```

Then, with the correct structure, I changed the draggable to the `.flip-container`, as I mentioned above:

```
$(".cards .flip-container").draggable({
```

And changed its `stop` handler to make the card flippable when dropped at the correct place, by adding the `onclick` callback:

```
stop: function (event, ui) {
    ui.helper.removeClass("draggable");
    var imgSrc = ui.helper.find("img")[0].src.split("/");
    var image = imgSrc[imgSrc.length - 1];
    if ($.ui.ddmanager.drop(ui.helper.data("draggable"), event)) {
         ui.helper.find(".flipper").attr("onclick", "this.classList.toggle('flipped')");            
    } else {

    }
}
```

Finally, added that styling to don't break the look and feel:

```
.flip-container, .front, .back {
    display: inline-block !important;
    height: 150px !important;
}
#dvDest img {
    margin: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: but I don't want the unselected cards ( outside the box ) to be flipped?;)

Comment: @HaltlolXD I've updated my answer and the fiddle accordingly.

Comment: You sir, helped me so very very much!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add your flip container flip classes to the images elements in you `html`.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/poi33/qbvzwsg2/3/)

I did not have time to make it pretty :P

Comment: Thanks! but I am looking for something that the cards can be flipped once they are dragged in the box, and not before;)